# Is the rheostat in a potentiometer compulsory to have?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

I've seen some constructions of potentiometer and all of them had a rheostat. Is it necessary for a potentiometer to have a rheostat? If yes, why?

Answer (score 0):

A rheostat or variable resistor is essentially a two terminal device in which the resistance between the two terminals can be changed.

A potentiometer is a three terminal device which allows the ratio of the resistances between a terminal connected to a moveable contact and each of the two end terminals to be altered.
A potentiometer can be used as a rheostat if only two of its terminals are used.

Comment: My question is whether or not a rheostat is compulsory in the construction of a potentiometer.

Comment: If the rheostat has three terminals it can be used as a potentiometer.  There are other ways of making a [potentiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer).